# How to Reset/Clear the multi column sorting in a NatTable?

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

In My example NatTable having 5 Columns. While creating nattable applying sorting for column 2 and 3 using SortColumnCommand(layer,position accumulate). It is applying sort in ASC order for column 2 and 3.

Now i want to Reset/Clear the column sorting for all columns, so that NatTable should not contain any sorting.

Is there any API or Mechanism to Reset/Clear the Sorting for all columns?
Or
Even it is fine to reset the columns one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the `ISortModel` this is one option. Another option would be to fire a `SortColumnCommand` with `SortDirectionEnum#NONE`.

```
natTable.doCommand(new SortColumnCommand(sortHeaderLayer, 0, SortDirectionEnum.NONE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the Answer:
We can  Remove all sorting by calling clear method on SortModel.

```
 this.colHeaderLayer.getSortHeaderLayer().getSortModel().clear();
```